# WordPress PDF Thumbnails & PHP 7.1 -- black backgrounds?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, imagemagick

I'm running WordPress on PHP 7.1.2 and the native PDF thumbnail generation in the media library (introduced in WP 4.7) generates the thumbnails, but with black backgrounds where they should be transparent.

I ran Debug Bar and it spat this out:

```
Active Editor   WP_Image_Editor_Imagick

Imagick Module Number   1673

ImageMagick Version ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-02-22 http://www.imagemagick.org

GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Ghostscript Version 9.18

Memory Limit    256M

Max Execution Time  30

Max Input Time  -1

Upload Max Filesize 512M

Post Max Size   1024M

Imagick area limit  2 GB

Imagick disk limit  -1

Imagick file limit  49152

Imagick map limit   2 GB

Imagick memory limit    989 MB

Imagick thread limit    1
```

Comment: Not sure if it would help, and not sure if you can upgrade it, but your **ImageMagick** is around 3 years old.

Comment: If you are saving the thumbnails as jpg it does not support transparency.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I just checked, and yes...WP is saving the PDF thumbnails as JPG's. Also @MarkSetchell -- thanks for the heads up on the ImageMagick version. I had updated the PHP wrapper to latest (as of writing - 3.4.3), but yeah turns out the underlying ImageMagick was super out of date.

Comment: @ConorBarclay I've got the same issue. Did you resolve it in the end? Did you just need to upgrade the version of ImageMagick?

Comment: Seems like a known issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39216